# Je n'ai pas encore utilisé de crayon(s?)

Tags: pluriel

Given that I have multiple pens (it could be any word instead of pen, just assume I have more than one of those).

Should I then plug a S at the end or no?

Comment: Welcome to French Stack Exchange! Remember, crayon = pencil, stylo = pen. Also, I'm not clear on your meaning. You haven't used pens at all, or you haven't used any of these particular pens? It affects the answer.

Comment: Can you tell what you would say in English?

Comment: I haven't used pens at all.

Answer (score 1):

It does not depend on the number of instruments you own. If, given the work you are doing with those instruments, it is clear that you need several (some sort of technical or artistic drawing, for instance), then when your words are to be understood in reference to this work, add an s. If it is clear that only one is needed, then use no s.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you are talking about

> I haven't used pens at all.

You could convey it with:

> Je n'ai pas du tout utilisé de stylos.

[Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/I%20haven%27t%20used%20pens%20at%20all) is quite reliable for sentences like this.